# Distance between first coordinate and rest of coordinates in each group in a dataframe in r

Tags: group-by, distance

I am trying to calculate distance between first coordinate and rest of coordinates in each group in a data frame in R.

I have different groups, with each group having different number of observations. There is another column that indicates the first point in each group.

I need to create another column that shows distance between first point and rest of points in each group.

My code looks like this.

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange(listNo) %>% mutate(dist=as.numeric(geodist(df[,10:11],df[1,10:11])))
```

But it keeps giving me error:
Error in mutate():
Caused by error:
dist must be size 49 or 1, not 42630.

Can someone please help me out here?

Thanks,
Leo